# How to filter multiple key name start with similar string key using Jmespath?

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I have below json from which i want to filter all mac address start with key macaddress_ using jmespath how to achieve this ?

```
{
  "facts_hash": {
    "macaddress_em1": "44:a8:42:27:c7:ba",
    "netmask_em1": "255.255.255.0",
    "mtu_em1": "1500",
    "macaddress_em2": "44:a8:42:27:c7:bb",
    "mtu_em2": "1500",
    "macaddress_em3": "44:a8:42:27:c7:bc",
    "mtu_em3": "1500",
    "macaddress_em4": "44:a8:42:27:c7:bd",
    "mtu_em4": "1500",

  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of json_query, it's possible to select the matching keys and extract the values. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_keys|
                 map('extract', facts_hash)|
                 list }}"
      vars:
        my_keys: "{{ facts_hash.keys()|
                     select('match', '^macaddress_(.*)$')|
                     list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": [
        "44:a8:42:27:c7:ba",
        "44:a8:42:27:c7:bb",
        "44:a8:42:27:c7:bc",
        "44:a8:42:27:c7:bd"
    ]
```